# I need a standalone script in web root but still have access to the database

Tags: xml, wp-load.php

I am building a specialized xml output script (can't use the built in export) and I have a file in the web root that I can call from the URL domain.com/myscript.php. However, I need to be able to do wordpress DB calls to get to the data. I have read you can load wp-load.php in the script - will that be enough?

Maybe there is some other (better) way of doing this but wordpress sends headers so I can't output a clean xml file without the wordpress clutter (header footer etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do that, including `wp-load.php` would bootstrap WordPress and allow you to query the database. I prefer to keep things encapsulated in plugins though, much more portable. You just need to hook early enough to send your own headers, and you can short-circuit the rest of the load process. For example-

```
function wpd_my_export_script() {
    if( isset( $_GET['do_my_export_stuff'] ) ) {
        header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
        // do your database stuff
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpd_my_export_script' );
```

Then visiting `http://example.com/?do_my_export_stuff` will trigger your code.

Comment: Milo, Thanks for the reply. I think what you suggest is what I'm looking for. However I have a query string in the URL like domain.com/myscript.php?lang=eng&output=xml&type=short. How would I handle that when visiting the URL.

Comment: Just append the extra GET vars to the end of the example URL I gave, but make sure you use GET vars that don't clash with [WordPress reserved terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms), otherwise you may trigger unexpected things.

Comment: Do you mean like this: domain.com/?do_my_export_stuff?lang=eng&output=xml&type=short

Comment: query strings start with a single `?`, multiple vars are separated by a `&`, so `domain.com/?do_my_export_stuff&lang=eng&output=xml&type=short`. but note that WordPress already uses `type`, you may need to change that.

Comment: THANKS MILO!!! I put that code in a plugin file and it works a treat. I'll fix the vars so they are unique.

Comment: I need to use meta data and so need to use get_post_meta - will that function work - I don't get any results from the call. I added global $wpdb; to the code.

Comment: yes, `get_post_meta` will work. you don't need `global $wpdb` unless you're calling `$wpdb` methods, like `$wpdb->get_results`, etc.. are you sure you're passing a valid post ID and key?